# How to render Overlay component just for a one time instead of rendering it in each Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

How to render Overlay component just for a one time instead of rendering it in each Route.

Here is code of my App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <div className='container'>
        <Sidebar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Overlay pathName={'Главная'} />} />
          <Route path='/orders' element={<Overlay pathName={'Заказы'} />} />
          <Route path='/products' element={<Overlay pathName={'Товары'} />} />
          <Route path='/reviews' element={<Overlay pathName={'Отзывы'} />} />
          <Route path='/checkout' element={<Overlay pathName={'Оформить заказ'} />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Add the code as text

Comment: I would use an array

Comment: Could u show me how? @KonradLinkowski

Comment: What would you render on each route instead of rendering `Overlay`? What is the goal here? Please also add a [mcve] of your code. Pictures of code are not accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DrewReese I'm sorry for that. There is a problem in editing issue

Comment: Can you share the `Overlay` component, what it renders? You could probably do a bit of a refactor to render it elsewhere but you'll likely still have the "branching" logic to render specific components on each route. I'm guessing that is what the `pathName` prop for the `Overlay` is for? That said, is there an issue with the current implementation? RRD is optimized and will effectively treat these 5 `Overlay` components as the same "instance", i.e. it's not going to unmount it just because the path changed unless the path changes to a route not rendering `Overlay`.

Comment: Yeah, you are completely right @DrewReese

Answer (score 0):

```js
<Routes>
{
[
{url:'/',pathname:'abc'},
{url:'/orders',pathname:'def'},
{url:'/products',pathname:'ghi'},
{url:'/reviews',pathname:'jkl'},
{url:'/checkout',pathname:'mno'},
].map(elem=><Route key={elem.url} path={elem.url} element={<Overlay pathname={elem.pathname}/>} />)
}
<Routes />
```

Comment: Answers typically include some sort of explanation of the issue and why a specific solution works. This ***still*** renders an `Overlay` component for each route. Let's wait for OP to actually clarify what they want and what any issue is.

Comment: @DrewReese he just said use the overlay component just once so i did.

Comment: Well, you are mapping 5 of them into the DOM, one for each array element, so no, there isn't just one `Overlay` component. OP's question is completely unclear and they need to provide more details.

Comment: its working fine i tried it many times @DrewReese

Comment: I'm sure it is. And I'm sure OP's code is working fine too. That's not the issue or question here though.

Comment: Yeah, actually @DrewReese is right, I just wanted not to render Overlay component in each route

Comment: if you are worrying about that react will render all overlay components then please check the documentation, i don't think it works like that. @RustamRavshanovich

Comment: Yes, I am about that. Thanks @ShreyanshGupta

Comment: @RustamRavshanovich yes then don't worry the router component will not render the overlay until you visit the path